# How can I make a <div> to grow upwards if its at the bottom of container <div>?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is that when the div "contacts" is clicked, the div "contacts_info" will show/hide which I have achieved.

The only problem when the item at the bottom of the list is clicked it will grow downward and the list will scroll in the container , but I would like it to grow upwards so that the "contacts_info" will be shown and no need to scroll down.

Below is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcrL7ocn/

```js
$('.contacts').on('click', function() {
  var next = $(this).next('.contacts_info');
     next.slideToggle(300);
     $('.contacts_info').not(next).slideUp(300);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="con_contacts">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <table style="width: 100%; padding: 10px;">
            <tr>
              <td class="td_left">Somers</td>
              <td class="td_right">3 Feb 15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="td_left">New Unit Trust Launch</td>
              <td class="td_right">Marketing</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts_info">
          asf
        </div>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle link not working.

Comment: feedle it or provide code you have...

Comment: i cant see anything on ur feedle

Comment: You can use scrollTop().

Comment: so you want last div up???

Comment: yes, if contacts_info div is taller than the allowed height.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put index in the list and track that index:

- if the index is smaller than the half of the list's `.length` you would use `slideDown()` for opening "contacts_info" and `slideUp()` for closing it.
- if the index is greater than the half of the list's `.length` you would use
  `slideUp()` for opening "contacts_info" and `slideDown()` for closing
  it.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jcrL7ocn/4/)**

Just add this line after `next.slideToggle(300)`

```
$("html").animate({ scrollTop: $(next).scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi Guruprasad Rao, i tried the demo but still the last item shows the "contatcs_info" below the border.

Comment: @sdcz6. Checking on it!!